# Using std::enable_shared_from_this in base classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to have a base class that privately inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this<TBASE>`. But then when I try to make a shared pointer to an object in a derived class, the compiler goes straight for the constructor in `std::enable_shared_from_this<TBASE>`, and so fails as it's an inaccessible base.

The example below fails to compile on g++ 5.2.1

```
#include <memory>

class Foo : private std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
    //...
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    //...
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> spBar(new Bar);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way I can specify within `Bar` not to try to use the inaccessible `shared_ptr` constructor?

The g++ error is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:82,
             from example.cxx:1:

/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of ‘std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = Bar; _Tp = Bar; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]’:

/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:117:32:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = Bar; _Tp = Bar]’

example.cxx:15:39:   required from here

/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:887:36: error: ‘std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Bar’
__enable_shared_from_this_helper(_M_refcount, __p, __p);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order not to expose `shared_from_this` you can make it `protected` (visible whithin whole hierarchy) or `private` (visible only inside the class) explicitly:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
private:
    using std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>::shared_from_this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `Foo`, not in `Bar`. The following program give the same error.

I think you must public inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this<>`

```
#include <memory>

class Foo : private std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
    //...
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    //...
};

int main()
{
    //std::shared_ptr<Bar> spBar(new Bar);
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> spBar(new Foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So there's no way of enabling `shared_from_this` for private use only?

Comment: I confirm the same problem with clang++ (3.5.0), with stdlib++ and with libc++